# Received an Argument error when expecting a routing error on in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

On a the beginner course Ruby on Rails 3 Essential Training with Kevin Skoglund, I am asked to add the following line of code into my routes.rb file.`match ':controller(/:action(/:id(.:format)))'` and comment out this line `get 'demo/index'`. According to the tutorial I should get a routing error but instead I get the following argument error. (You should not use the `match` method in your router without specifying an HTTP method. If you want to expose your action to both GET and POST, add `via: [:get, :post]` option. If you want to expose your action to GET, use `get` in the router: Instead of: match "controller#action" Do: get "controller#action").

Comment: well, that sounds like good advice. Have you tried that?

Comment: I did, and it does make the web app work, I added the `via: [:get, :post]` after the `match` code. But I'm supposed to get the routing error for the homepage at least. This is supposed to teach us about the concept of "rails default routing". @jjk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are taking a course designed for Rails 3, but are using Rails 4. That is why you are having trouble! `match` was changed in Rails 4.

Comment: oh my god, that explains a ton thank you. @dan philips

Comment: No problem! In case you want a good tutorial for Rails 4, this one is always highly recommended:

[Rails Tutorial by Michael Hartl](https://www.railstutorial.org/book)